# Different height of tikz subfigures despite same axis width/height

Tags: tikz-pgf, matlab2tikz

Why do the subfigures in this document have different heights despite having the same axis width/height? How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{float,subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz,tikzscale}
\usepackage{pgfplots,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[5]

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{.5\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Some A}
    \includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{larger.tikz}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}{.5\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Some B}
    \includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{smaller.tikz}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Why is subfigure B not the same height as A}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

This is the larger figure (**larger.tikz**)

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
scaled ticks=false,
width=5.812in,
height=4.754in,
at={(0.975in,0.642in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=800,
xtick={50,150,250,350,450,550,650,750},
xmajorgrids,
ymin=0.2,
ymax=2.2,
ymajorgrids,
axis background/.style={fill=white}
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1,solid,line width=1.5pt]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
50  0.841471627133954\\
100 1.72723135413374\\
150 2.1405396424556\\
200 2.13102098564617\\
250 1.89482005419699\\
300 1.53838194288435\\
350 1.40578022538911\\
400 1.42164242831094\\
450 1.37921866977304\\
500 1.22212863128566\\
550 0.959402192179795\\
600 0.905573207120867\\
650 0.861693789248431\\
700 0.818458283851262\\
750 0.611413859120316\\
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

And the smaller figure (**smaller.tikz**).

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
scaled ticks=false,
width=5.812in,
height=4.754in,
at={(0.975in,0.642in)},
scale only axis,
unbounded coords=jump,
xmin=732313,
xmax=735965,
xtick={732678,733043,733408,733774,734139,734504,734869,735235,735600},
xticklabels={{2006},{2007},{2008},{2009},{2010},{2011},{2012},{2013},{2014}},
xmajorgrids,
ymin=-0.5,
ymax=2.5,
ymajorgrids,
axis background/.style={fill=white}
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1,solid,line width=1.5pt]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
732315  0\\
732318  nan\\
732323  nan\\
732326  nan\\
732332  nan\\
732337  nan\\
732340  nan\\
732345  nan\\
732350  nan\\
732353  nan\\
732358  nan\\
732361  nan\\
732367  nan\\
732372  nan\\
732375  nan\\
732380  nan\\
732385  nan\\
732388  nan\\
732393  nan\\
732399  nan\\
732402  nan\\
732407  nan\\
732410  nan\\
732415  nan\\
732420  nan\\
732423  nan\\
732428  nan\\
732431  nan\\
732436  nan\\
732441  nan\\
732444  nan\\
732449  nan\\
732452  nan\\
732457  nan\\
732463  nan\\
732466  nan\\
732471  nan\\
732476  nan\\
732479  nan\\
732484  nan\\
732487  nan\\
732492  nan\\
732498  nan\\
732501  nan\\
732506  nan\\
732511  nan\\
732514  nan\\
732519  nan\\
732522  nan\\
732527  nan\\
732532  nan\\
732535  nan\\
732540  nan\\
732543  nan\\
732548  nan\\
732553  nan\\
732556  nan\\
732562  nan\\
732567  nan\\
732570  nan\\
732575  nan\\
732578  nan\\
732583  nan\\
732588  nan\\
732591  nan\\
732596  nan\\
732599  nan\\
732604  nan\\
732609  -0.00487896766202536\\
732612  -0.00577763982855989\\
732617  0.0167084825274807\\
732620  0.0451723575857316\\
732625  0.0227771106581538\\
732630  0.0220911179243386\\
732633  0.0277934611174928\\
732638  0.0559585833483644\\
732644  0.0791061471854018\\
732647  0.0605482352696342\\
732652  0.07951143949088\\
732655  0.0828761627703003\\
732660  0.0874131920017132\\
732665  0.0739673660431742\\
732668  0.0804452145326178\\
732674  0.0781327871486407\\
732680  0.0697756682373585\\
732683  0.122507179499203\\
732688  0.160607057730153\\
732694  0.174288138800443\\
732697  0.192568396586079\\
732702  0.189246117818535\\
732707  0.224537358160884\\
732710  0.22592629648608\\
732715  0.225481893023854\\
732718  0.196872558457448\\
732723  0.185975772181394\\
732729  0.206732384071934\\
732732  0.213808472964773\\
732737  0.225118589973574\\
732742  0.253378251897546\\
732745  0.216566788953216\\
732750  0.212038823916812\\
732753  0.237388653763508\\
732758  0.223579381992098\\
732763  0.236767978549741\\
732766  0.259741904998308\\
732771  0.254219483787764\\
732774  0.268842262164694\\
732779  0.266487645027219\\
732785  0.273774117223629\\
732788  0.325151790565587\\
732793  0.3018281702407\\
732798  0.300890511302459\\
732801  0.313556690119367\\
732806  0.352365570714856\\
732809  0.359322169078667\\
732814  0.309875479610169\\
732819  0.260942898129839\\
732822  0.250071163194532\\
732828  0.276924944522573\\
732833  0.321388724507179\\
732836  0.238481025536282\\
732841  0.206107821842801\\
732844  0.240992167371088\\
732849  0.214823651149398\\
732854  0.255542970370694\\
732857  0.246610505373935\\
732863  0.350061282458589\\
732868  0.314571863248009\\
732871  0.308957277666199\\
732876  0.272926514564889\\
732879  0.320786293040118\\
732884  0.338165037813269\\
732889  0.324881828286102\\
732892  0.291182644280021\\
732897  0.299523110787242\\
732900  0.259046815978688\\
732905  0.256494745961608\\
732910  0.262988231417277\\
732913  0.248203953396918\\
732918  0.252448166367148\\
732921  0.238319014777556\\
732927  0.223523846328046\\
732932  0.22014347977142\\
732935  0.245349178293802\\
732940  0.249053946184575\\
732945  0.23575207862621\\
732948  0.272895160619354\\
732953  0.247102121718211\\
732956  0.283088537158098\\
732961  0.287414298415549\\
732966  0.310761322688188\\
732969  0.33649889955197\\
732974  0.333635587686433\\
732977  0.349721023785605\\
732982  0.3329153595607\\
732987  0.287180474660942\\
732990  0.297312351689638\\
732995  0.286663784974553\\
732998  0.300698269550215\\
733003  0.304672684381396\\
733009  0.2837991489817\\
733012  0.294666616013697\\
733017  0.303697578654637\\
733022  0.288446542957594\\
733025  0.287196440834458\\
733030  0.294253259588148\\
733033  0.291063793264915\\
733039  0.297521726794251\\
733046  0.296642251414814\\
733051  0.295712090785603\\
733054  0.306111338852049\\
733060  0.30931542157398\\
733065  0.285851815361828\\
733068  0.294120176603655\\
733073  0.307442703046471\\
733078  0.317017633247049\\
733081  0.332278627078165\\
733086  0.310112537762629\\
733089  0.325999241803597\\
733095  0.335161846990365\\
733100  0.315892211151718\\
733103  0.294893640387428\\
733108  0.293215535871241\\
733113  0.314149903045062\\
733116  0.303200392289472\\
733121  0.326038800346932\\
733124  0.343287024816532\\
733129  0.336473622211881\\
733134  0.332755704278273\\
733137  0.350500449410711\\
733143  0.354437123818549\\
733148  0.359761356316362\\
733151  0.363370947569634\\
733156  0.375885450293301\\
733159  0.383198875946806\\
733164  0.351347576578618\\
733169  0.370376728822511\\
733172  0.367383290767411\\
733177  0.352577616323907\\
733180  0.33619758646071\\
733185  0.355131344132772\\
733191  0.339303759412488\\
733194  0.371063420267581\\
733199  0.368643773246626\\
733204  0.34630658207181\\
733207  0.357177780781223\\
733212  0.378040990988239\\
733215  0.376966640652688\\
733220  0.353712610487247\\
733225  0.368980387293373\\
733229  0.408383769629047\\
733234  0.412922424425429\\
733239  0.442664535852572\\
733242  0.448139107895135\\
733247  0.439384654983117\\
733250  0.395469817277657\\
733255  0.411412244452283\\
733260  0.411679049892694\\
733263  0.467405960143934\\
733268  0.453089782224766\\
733271  0.359679049938561\\
733276  0.427053905875006\\
733281  0.460959138624126\\
733284  0.444839326825838\\
733290  0.48643438697396\\
733295  0.475929381191843\\
733298  0.496987869169641\\
733303  0.502874551405903\\
733306  0.542165358612321\\
733311  0.547720634208547\\
733316  0.567960520572162\\
733319  0.564558009592754\\
733324  0.577857737559013\\
733327  0.622516691152033\\
733332  0.623803392129967\\
733337  0.59433605821695\\
733340  0.614708377563296\\
733345  0.667285786018484\\
733348  0.634845506654359\\
733353  0.677463103705172\\
733358  0.637314038733905\\
733361  0.608272703334497\\
733366  0.577892969233596\\
733372  0.595130048863903\\
733375  0.63184816576438\\
733380  0.633510191053829\\
733383  0.671978078121037\\
733388  0.657236236983061\\
733393  0.652140353729717\\
733396  0.634018423367537\\
733402  0.682338542422953\\
733407  0.684792262790229\\
733411  0.694306721923903\\
733416  0.649244379615951\\
733421  0.672048205482966\\
733424  0.637676283359989\\
733430  0.601339577868562\\
733435  0.615642092948983\\
733438  0.623363647324768\\
733443  0.64238692063184\\
733446  0.627646188611386\\
733451  0.649476853091117\\
733457  0.653059308520578\\
733460  0.660534128435426\\
733465  0.674829502614163\\
733470  0.659491013233874\\
733473  0.659545530115582\\
733478  0.650603080468386\\
733481  0.658125626154044\\
733486  0.659288703261247\\
733492  0.655065716299005\\
733495  0.659797468191649\\
733500  0.659476296135259\\
733505  0.664603036130936\\
733508  0.666112215080053\\
733513  0.667895050792445\\
733516  0.668262639045082\\
733521  0.668492554159293\\
733526  0.666461714958171\\
733529  0.662026488463143\\
733534  0.66295408875253\\
733537  0.663928010423103\\
733542  0.664258548959125\\
733547  0.669296724015447\\
733550  0.663868984619663\\
733556  0.655619202646231\\
733561  0.663321265598015\\
733564  0.66903668712735\\
733569  0.693953608673099\\
733572  0.689381107694228\\
733577  0.701209159863874\\
733582  0.697239520750387\\
733585  0.695910488528674\\
733590  0.69042076796451\\
733596  0.687207091018458\\
733599  0.685700782792561\\
733604  0.6877122878183\\
733607  0.68189202006611\\
733612  0.68088342889526\\
733617  0.673859734277193\\
733620  0.673859734277193\\
733625  0.663082460418608\\
733628  0.660830157316463\\
733633  0.660830157316463\\
733638  0.660164986076284\\
733641  0.660164986076284\\
733646  0.660164986076284\\
733649  0.660164986076284\\
733655  0.658986111105455\\
733660  0.652493927862076\\
733663  0.650505047071963\\
733668  0.652393511181639\\
733673  0.652393511181639\\
733676  0.648826987151779\\
733681  0.648826987151779\\
733684  0.648826987151779\\
733689  0.648826987151779\\
733694  0.648826987151779\\
733697  0.648826987151779\\
733702  0.648826987151779\\
733705  0.648826987151779\\
733710  0.648826987151779\\
733715  0.648826987151779\\
733718  0.644499076027022\\
733723  0.644499076027022\\
733726  0.644499076027022\\
733731  0.644499076027022\\
733736  0.644499076027022\\
733740  0.644499076027022\\
733745  0.644499076027022\\
733750  0.644499076027022\\
733753  0.644499076027022\\
733758  0.644499076027022\\
733761  0.644499076027022\\
733766  0.644499076027022\\
733772  0.644499076027022\\
733778  0.644499076027022\\
733781  0.644499076027022\\
733786  0.644499076027022\\
733789  0.644499076027022\\
733795  0.644499076027022\\
733800  0.644499076027022\\
733803  0.644499076027022\\
733808  0.644499076027022\\
733813  0.644499076027022\\
733816  0.644499076027022\\
733822  0.644499076027022\\
733827  0.644499076027022\\
733830  0.644499076027022\\
733835  0.644499076027022\\
733838  0.644499076027022\\
733843  0.644499076027022\\
733848  0.644499076027022\\
733851  0.644499076027022\\
733856  0.644499076027022\\
733859  0.644499076027022\\
733864  0.644499076027022\\
733869  0.644499076027022\\
733872  0.644499076027022\\
733878  0.644499076027022\\
733883  0.644499076027022\\
733886  0.643645627140099\\
733891  0.643645627140099\\
733894  0.625161004843066\\
733899  0.620425484627214\\
733904  0.613701243096032\\
733907  0.613701243096032\\
733912  0.613701243096032\\
733915  0.606993788692864\\
733921  0.606993788692864\\
733926  0.606993788692864\\
733929  0.606993788692864\\
733934  0.606993788692864\\
733939  0.615391578748097\\
733942  0.606930824415784\\
733947  0.606930824415784\\
733950  0.606930824415784\\
733955  0.610306586121771\\
733961  0.605715320724236\\
733964  0.605715320724236\\
733969  0.613202275131333\\
733974  0.61586579618678\\
733977  0.618990134459931\\
733982  0.61919408647178\\
733985  0.644433867199506\\
733990  0.667257803440671\\
733995  0.665997752917605\\
733998  0.663214072148951\\
734003  0.635432290610764\\
734006  0.6730361388428\\
734011  0.685783993988622\\
734016  0.671669436765607\\
734019  0.63316245049212\\
734025  0.679755239993354\\
734030  0.703267104504953\\
734033  0.715919752009543\\
734038  0.7098964364328\\
734041  0.677632079944259\\
734046  0.693883652195535\\
734051  0.648795535621392\\
734054  0.704570363934662\\
734059  0.731034992120739\\
734062  0.749431530448288\\
734067  0.737485410319522\\
734072  0.721706943954738\\
734075  0.645613976813975\\
734080  0.649832374125532\\
734083  0.658352550816523\\
734088  0.691085019790961\\
734093  0.694864809679721\\
734096  0.693269003236412\\
734101  0.685367873933538\\
734107  0.667679704668863\\
734110  0.70371910165674\\
734115  0.710740409741651\\
734118  0.713835868794212\\
734123  0.73264751288795\\
734128  0.733911996867178\\
734131  0.76560046108191\\
734137  0.769988778990821\\
734143  0.773233749976381\\
734146  0.779191784077404\\
734151  0.75409844101035\\
734157  0.755575700074558\\
734160  0.738768898728087\\
734165  0.700763261566369\\
734170  0.672565448068621\\
734173  0.722039812118098\\
734178  0.696087671874785\\
734181  0.738203205859888\\
734187  0.774492098514323\\
734192  0.785803201075499\\
734195  0.78684203112899\\
734200  0.837665590676055\\
734205  0.846841327304078\\
734208  0.864307854738449\\
734213  0.864431379045813\\
734216  0.867847909455432\\
734221  0.882335953642482\\
734226  0.884654386985979\\
734229  0.885776715057633\\
734235  0.904986494068693\\
734240  0.913973563427494\\
734243  0.924955673952627\\
734248  0.900532930284329\\
734251  0.925513659710965\\
734256  0.90377143047995\\
734261  0.9054760022222\\
734264  0.89166717671802\\
734269  0.887000224952905\\
734272  0.914985582491546\\
734277  0.874846536726226\\
734282  0.844596752585867\\
734285  0.85834287349675\\
734291  0.864895815023225\\
734296  0.883987050426637\\
734299  0.882219986659938\\
734304  0.937613273197205\\
734307  0.97846298784823\\
734312  0.932995040813622\\
734317  0.920697642049507\\
734320  0.859316751969955\\
734326  0.827664184522074\\
734331  0.887695976408437\\
734334  0.90764232416779\\
734339  0.868571760279665\\
734342  0.886373757444997\\
734347  0.916080713148141\\
734352  0.907351337899747\\
734355  0.921412000286907\\
734360  0.920207258278598\\
734363  0.901865108868096\\
734368  0.915689997002233\\
734373  0.901858401382469\\
734376  0.87612804335047\\
734381  0.871501702971892\\
734384  0.931454623977207\\
734390  0.946518244208817\\
734395  0.959903426976423\\
734398  0.964950170972972\\
734403  0.988080411092553\\
734408  1.00829205298915\\
734411  1.02614958885811\\
734416  1.0110196171098\\
734419  1.02126655046236\\
734424  1.04224103805801\\
734429  1.04042691403524\\
734432  1.03761398136429\\
734437  1.05700780487402\\
734440  1.06666227895151\\
734445  1.07882598547416\\
734450  1.10493621155163\\
734453  1.10640904857837\\
734458  1.08395103677522\\
734461  1.0935044377551\\
734466  1.10837917019405\\
734472  1.12669341773016\\
734475  1.15788710033255\\
734480  1.15381889451184\\
734485  1.16603918941471\\
734488  1.14703647728324\\
734493  1.16915875165679\\
734499  1.1806661301186\\
734502  1.18323352761363\\
734507  1.19338529545575\\
734510  1.19426224158445\\
734515  1.20517844889703\\
734521  1.21155447145644\\
734524  1.1684347726066\\
734529  1.17772800190166\\
734534  1.21278711883505\\
734537  1.23045857064813\\
734542  1.27237457977132\\
734545  1.29315270534708\\
734550  1.31561512380677\\
734556  1.32985016082116\\
734559  1.29468809867368\\
734564  1.29894470355432\\
734569  1.32701549893745\\
734572  1.30734281411102\\
734577  1.29634702342929\\
734580  1.27746854743632\\
734585  1.28520824592207\\
734590  1.32002350357349\\
734593  1.33966603245279\\
734598  1.34656718477347\\
734601  1.32608707546651\\
734606  1.29399672841788\\
734611  1.306673995707\\
734614  1.32429165494195\\
734620  1.33949690090633\\
734625  1.34103206856598\\
734628  1.30951328000151\\
734633  1.3297250498731\\
734636  1.34243835647262\\
734641  1.31351623248138\\
734646  1.3300108827538\\
734649  1.34259017062756\\
734655  1.36658871964575\\
734660  1.32261915755532\\
734663  1.29393314837088\\
734668  1.2776095497742\\
734671  1.27743431013124\\
734676  1.31013591664866\\
734681  1.29409099550394\\
734684  1.32495411278228\\
734690  1.34956893398923\\
734695  1.35495376902436\\
734698  1.32999752403563\\
734703  1.3130989101547\\
734706  1.34460343915159\\
734711  1.33532802125852\\
734716  1.28843518053839\\
734719  1.25576869680179\\
734724  1.09088985851862\\
734727  1.1775319843835\\
734732  1.2136542456514\\
734737  1.12121358794045\\
734740  1.18485242324915\\
734745  1.22299304882624\\
734748  1.21973858654773\\
734754  1.2367492357105\\
734759  1.21182563549019\\
734762  1.26515165055616\\
734767  1.26816259589278\\
734772  1.21652715008499\\
734775  1.20521043200264\\
734780  1.14252930967049\\
734783  1.21034200500739\\
734788  1.22142281524996\\
734793  1.24435806773977\\
734796  1.22476532341165\\
734801  1.26317662507565\\
734804  1.2620274416548\\
734809  1.23731182789879\\
734814  1.23146268636607\\
734817  1.21341985833783\\
734822  1.21787679875482\\
734825  1.19073086982743\\
734830  1.18529004330339\\
734836  1.1817159941512\\
734839  1.18852713170677\\
734844  1.17700179163484\\
734849  1.17228322452596\\
734852  1.15949175252241\\
734857  1.1635103197983\\
734860  1.17109832690713\\
734866  1.18040273396189\\
734872  1.1760543206064\\
734877  1.20450275333329\\
734880  1.20603029070965\\
734886  1.22764441954937\\
734891  1.2313673795763\\
734894  1.25121740121014\\
734899  1.25128115403725\\
734902  1.26199758133763\\
734907  1.27969778195953\\
734912  1.28797289527938\\
734915  1.28851176487574\\
734921  1.28195375278501\\
734926  1.28753011495571\\
734929  1.28442424873231\\
734934  1.29528401733316\\
734937  1.30083171845501\\
734942  1.32593198660543\\
734947  1.32721461218083\\
734950  1.33835962547712\\
734955  1.35293866468503\\
734958  1.34119711172665\\
734963  1.35536677369282\\
734969  1.35114521384748\\
734972  1.36103429106266\\
734977  1.35609016728239\\
734982  1.35861041302713\\
734985  1.36750192817183\\
734990  1.37497728767751\\
734993  1.38527795731465\\
734998  1.36049875980375\\
735003  1.36528082251665\\
735006  1.35864501976201\\
735011  1.33182741692488\\
735014  1.36000068062517\\
735020  1.35376579424128\\
735025  1.3076205501946\\
735028  1.31940878184597\\
735033  1.3249452866041\\
735038  1.32175767842967\\
735041  1.34725232763513\\
735046  1.31863507747034\\
735049  1.32459892513801\\
735055  1.35473093581502\\
735060  1.35152752056079\\
735063  1.33555226030211\\
735068  1.34952366180594\\
735073  1.33450278576643\\
735076  1.32086485073101\\
735081  1.34783732850949\\
735084  1.32657798990451\\
735089  1.33595920720124\\
735094  1.33994181438197\\
735097  1.34560994756628\\
735102  1.35104484466009\\
735105  1.36074128364613\\
735110  1.3671646298953\\
735116  1.37334922904813\\
735119  1.40090053146071\\
735124  1.38703868445077\\
735129  1.43131908842463\\
735132  1.42354464406234\\
735137  1.40063761272458\\
735140  1.38953722448782\\
735145  1.38950264927684\\
735150  1.40747492157529\\
735153  1.3732866647312\\
735158  1.36710581277958\\
735161  1.3839716185735\\
735166  1.35625290537461\\
735173  1.34625922523035\\
735178  1.35454642335738\\
735181  1.34789938204028\\
735186  1.32724098818705\\
735189  1.30415705858008\\
735194  1.3623379131518\\
735200  1.36557796705205\\
735203  1.38660926523676\\
735208  1.37615712792885\\
735213  1.38815149795132\\
735216  1.39393194942141\\
735221  1.40000737725419\\
735224  1.40493763682061\\
735230  1.38704766569283\\
735236  1.38844729675193\\
735241  1.44407504814884\\
735244  1.45221362276749\\
735249  1.45588599668176\\
735252  1.46441972871215\\
735258  1.46789739149475\\
735263  1.46131528232071\\
735266  1.47341181086316\\
735271  1.47588106818801\\
735276  1.49271955118575\\
735279  1.49715806633907\\
735285  1.50521545478627\\
735290  1.4623708491651\\
735293  1.47326303593517\\
735298  1.49073241855478\\
735301  1.49481213438004\\
735306  1.49931045433121\\
735311  1.50291233786647\\
735314  1.5104716337356\\
735319  1.49068954444783\\
735325  1.50127541388163\\
735328  1.45241831689487\\
735333  1.46232791728798\\
735336  1.48238426842121\\
735341  1.46522576976239\\
735346  1.44446126304586\\
735349  1.51506140057649\\
735354  1.52010003598671\\
735357  1.52570896938705\\
735362  1.54873484722291\\
735367  1.55965636830229\\
735370  1.58521954887122\\
735375  1.59390016700846\\
735378  1.57796398722791\\
735384  1.57996597783447\\
735389  1.56632386805598\\
735392  1.54298932827318\\
735397  1.55264540254699\\
735402  1.55193647424995\\
735405  1.57434561606602\\
735410  1.53743426127547\\
735413  1.57733105795598\\
735418  1.57082531583262\\
735424  1.58339614705917\\
735427  1.58998221183792\\
735432  1.60223783140083\\
735437  1.62578712385733\\
735440  1.62090239637121\\
735445  1.62603897628274\\
735448  1.65036739404998\\
735453  1.643537942241\\
735458  1.6318916879202\\
735461  1.62341576929202\\
735466  1.59270439932403\\
735469  1.60876419242712\\
735474  1.57563800834181\\
735480  1.58896230452708\\
735483  1.63102507331789\\
735488  1.67566425297975\\
735493  1.67737324113519\\
735496  1.68918669330077\\
735501  1.66298725023637\\
735504  1.68029308797252\\
735509  1.68630070889962\\
735514  1.69860988835512\\
735517  1.65774000321889\\
735522  1.68714853895376\\
735525  1.70836510317472\\
735530  1.72075100787439\\
735535  1.71160652020152\\
735538  1.71656224955561\\
735543  1.73777426696388\\
735546  1.7116776117778\\
735551  1.74689337587008\\
735556  1.76388303836051\\
735559  1.75074344869943\\
735564  1.80080081315136\\
735570  1.80359377175064\\
735573  1.7834871810641\\
735578  1.81055156758506\\
735581  1.80672098430962\\
735586  1.80794440317506\\
735591  1.83087945877429\\
735595  1.84615782007944\\
735601  1.845116878629\\
735606  1.83222263127904\\
735609  1.86074214328398\\
735614  1.87159585466831\\
735620  1.88639227480843\\
735623  1.91711975064858\\
735628  1.90665513381797\\
735633  1.91365568146817\\
735636  1.89481293471328\\
735641  1.94251407479009\\
735644  1.97006230724637\\
735650  1.9734042078003\\
735655  2.00001666625985\\
735658  2.00253478324067\\
735663  2.02161678309061\\
735668  2.00859638685525\\
735671  2.00255636135711\\
735676  1.98470175928765\\
735679  1.99680454008399\\
735684  1.96278189506195\\
735689  1.93858031891614\\
735692  1.98803032687148\\
735697  1.90160068716179\\
735700  1.88705217653983\\
735705  1.87682869295834\\
735711  1.93712852737466\\
735714  1.96960182518643\\
735719  1.93404056975421\\
735724  1.958694852332\\
735727  1.95521095258658\\
735732  1.96269550298217\\
735735  1.9391422059517\\
735740  1.94633404388462\\
735746  1.9845790385442\\
735749  2.01353059567091\\
735754  2.02195102949169\\
735759  2.04063526616203\\
735762  2.03998377865387\\
735767  2.0290175510426\\
735770  2.03716125695376\\
735775  2.02464824355248\\
735780  2.02826993358089\\
735783  2.06100703385306\\
735789  2.03889974490565\\
735794  2.05326125492947\\
735797  2.06299689569461\\
735802  2.0697719076923\\
735805  2.07507129378636\\
735810  2.05257822589515\\
735815  2.03212003428309\\
735818  2.01704144266256\\
735823  2.02183543472158\\
735826  2.04333860679405\\
735831  2.06985392279302\\
735836  2.07427508316233\\
735839  2.07447155223647\\
735845  2.08073212195102\\
735850  2.08437032214376\\
735853  2.08209347922694\\
735858  2.05014970375894\\
735861  2.07972990125394\\
735866  2.04318279856218\\
735871  2.05286276929381\\
735874  2.01098570541961\\
735879  2.02060554708411\\
735882  1.98174087574493\\
735887  1.92922848875368\\
735892  1.94480864125062\\
735895  1.98578420039284\\
735900  2.01215200428925\\
735903  2.02935107679225\\
735908  2.05780427986922\\
735913  2.0511034648128\\
735916  2.05680833896575\\
735921  2.05732008871795\\
735924  2.072537724067\\
735929  2.08367529011899\\
735935  2.08713836258961\\
735938  2.12857773178255\\
735943  2.12367270129574\\
735948  2.10057577040493\\
735951  2.10768113053332\\
735956  2.13350247756152\\
735962  2.13300450106408\\
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Comment: To answer why: In the output from `matlab2tikz` the size of the axis boxes (not including ticklabels) are the same, due to the `scale only axis` and the same `height`/`width` setting in the `axis` options. But `tikzscale` sets the *total* width, including ticklabels, to `\columnwidth`. And the yticklabels in `smaller.tikz` are wider, because of the minus sign. Wider ticklabels, but same total width, leads to smaller size of the axis box.

Comment: But the problem persists if I comment out scale-only-axis, why is that?

Comment: Right, `scale only axis` doesn't actually matter in this context, I realize. Without it, `pgfplots` sets the size (width and height) of the axis box to the defined size minus 45pt. The defined size is the same for both axes, so the size of the axes boxes will be the same, and you're left with the same situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

changes in your code, which enable above image:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{float,subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz,tikzscale}
\usepackage{pgfplots,lipsum}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15, width=\textwidth} % <---
```

then

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{.45\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Some A}
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
scaled ticks=false,
%width=5.812in,         % <---
%height=4.754in,        % <---
%at={(0.975in,0.642in)},% <---
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=800,
xtick={50,150,250,350,450,550,650,750},
xmajorgrids,
ymin=0.2,
ymax=2.2,
ymajorgrids,
axis background/.style={fill=white}
]
```

and

```
\end{subfigure}
    \hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.45\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \caption{Some B}
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
scaled ticks=false,
%width=5.812in,         % <---
%height=4.754in,        % <---
%at={(0.975in,0.642in)},% <---
scale only axis,
unbounded coords=jump,
xmin=732313,
xmax=735965,
xtick={732678,733043,733408,733774,734139,734504,734869,735235,735600},
xticklabels={{2006},,{2008},,{2010},,{2012},,{2014}}, % <---
xmajorgrids,
ymin=-0.5,
ymax=2.5,
ymajorgrids,
axis background/.style={fill=white}
]
```

Comment: I get "ERROR: Package pgfkeys Error: Choice '1.15' unknown in choice key '/pgfplots/compat/anchors'. I am going to ignore this key" Using e.g. compat=1.5 lets me compile but then the subfigures are differently scaled.

Comment: @mwater, then is time to upgrade your `pgfplots` instalation ... till to do this, reduce version 1.15 to version of your `pgfplots`. (you not provide this information, good habits is always set `pgfplotset` with version of used package).

Comment: I updated to TexLive 2017 and now I can compile with compat=1.15, but the subfigures are still differently scaled. Any other ideas?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and use AUCTeX btw.

Comment: than you have in your code something different that i have mine (composed from code snippets). i cant help you further, if you will not consider my firs comment below your question. so, please again, make from your code snippets one, complete document, which will have included your directly in document (instead `\includegraphics`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked! I had to remove the [witdth=\textwidth] option from \includegraphics then it turned out right.